# Update existing JSON

Tags: php, json

Suppose I have the following JSON structure:

```
{"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

How can I update it and add another attribute, e.g. age, using PHP?
This is my expected result:

```
{"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "age":"20"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith", "age":"30"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones", "age":"40"}
]}
```

**Update:**

This is my approach:

```
$json1 = '{"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}';

$json2 = '{"employees":[
    {"age":"20"},
    {"age":"30"},
    {"age":"40"}
]}';

$data1 = json_decode($json1, true);
$data2 = json_decode($json2, true);

$i = 0;
foreach ($data1 as $key => $entry) {
    $data1[$key][$i] += $data2["employees"][$i];
    $i++;
}

$json1 = json_encode($data1);
echo ($json1)
```

But unfortunately, I get only that result:

```
{  
   "employees":[  
      {  
         "firstName":"John",
         "lastName":"Doe",
         "age":"20"
      },
      {  
         "firstName":"Anna",
         "lastName":"Smith"
      },
      {  
         "firstName":"Peter",
         "lastName":"Jones"
      }
   ]
}
```

So it only adds it to the very first entry.

Comment: Parse it. Modify the resulting arrays. Serialize it. What's the problem?

Comment: @close-voters the question has been edited within passable quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over your array. At the moment you are looping over the object, so the first item is `employees` and then there are no more items.

```
foreach ($data1['employees'] as $key => $entry) {
    $data1['employees'][$key] += $data2["employees"][$key];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It depends on the language that you are using the json file but basically is a

```
for employe in json['employees']:
    employe['age'] = '20'
```

but for this method the age of all employees would '20', I would do something like:

```
ages ={'John':'20','Anna':'30','Peter':'40'}
for employe in json['employess']:
   name = employe['firstname'] 
   age= ages[name]
   employe[name] = age
```

for javascript:

```
var ages ={'John':'20','Anna':'30','Peter':'40'}
for(var i=0;i<json['employees'].length;i++){
    var employe = json['employees'][i];
    var name = employe[name];
    var age = ages[name];
    employe[name] = age;
};
```

Comment: "It depends on the language that you are using" — The question is tagged PHP